# How to tell apart prototype table view cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Say I have a table view with a single prototype cell in it that contains a stack view. I'd like each cell of the table view generated from the prototype cell to have different views in the stack view. So, I need to find a way to tell table view cells apart.

If the table view had static cells, I could just use the tag property of the cell and populate stack views easily. Though, using static cells is probably not the best approach since cells are almost identical to each other.

What can I do to populate stack view differently depending on the "row" of the table view cells?

Comment: Isn't that precisely what you should be doing in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: thanks @jcaron! I blame myself for not thinking about that. Feel free to copy/paste your comment to answer this question and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's precisely what you should be doing in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.